# If at all, how is it possible to detect that CMakeLists.txt is run by 'emcmake cmake' instead of just 'cmake'?

Tags: cmake, emscripten, emcmake

I have a project that shall be configured/built differently when either using `cmake` or `emcmake cmake` (followed by `make` or `emmake make` respectively). For example, I don't need to build a test executable if it is run by `emcmake cmake` as the result will be WebAssembly.

So, is there any variable available when run by `emcmake cmake`, that I could query? Are there other approaches?

Comment: How are you calling these commands? Wouldn't a wrapper script work for you with setting the environment variable for the respective command that you can access later in the CMake to identify the source of invocation?

Comment: @Azeem `emcmake` is already such a wrapper script (by emscripten). Of course, I could write my own wrapper script that wraps `emcmake` or I could call one of the commands (`cmake` or `emcmake cmake`) with additional parameters, but as I am already using different commands, I was hoping to be able to detect that, without additional "surroundings".

Comment: Right. That could be a solution just to get things done. And, it could be suggested as an improvement/feature to `emscripten`'s codebase for future support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect if `emcmake cmake` or `emconfigure cmake` are used with the `EMSCRIPTEN` variable:

```
if(EMSCRIPTEN)
    message("Using emscripten!")
else()
    message("Not using emscripten!")
endif()
```